# Timeout exception in android studio while trying to get a response from an asp.net web api call

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume an asp.net web api in android that takes around 17500 ms to respond(as per postman). It is giving me a timeout error in android studio.
But when I try to explicitly run the api using postman I am getting the desired result.

Here is the snippet:

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(vehicleurl);
java.net.HttpURLConnection conn = (java.net.HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000000);


Request req = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(vehicleurl)
                        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(req).execute();
```

Comment: Could you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your code ？

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you please suggest me where to add this code?I am very new to android.Do you want me to add it in the manifest?Also looks like this is for access denied exception,whereas im getting a timed out exception.

Comment: You can try like my answer.

Comment: I would love to but I dont think its gonna solve my problem.

Comment: You use `HttpURLConnection` or other network request . I saw different in your code.

Comment: I am using HttpUrlConnection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

in your `manifest`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Edit**

HttpURLConnection

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 // edit here ,change time
 connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
 connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
```

OKHttp

```
private final OkHttpClient client;

public ConfigureTimeouts() throws Exception {
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
}
```

Comment: Its already there in my manifest. I dont think this is gonna solve the problem.

Comment: You can try again.@sai1990

Comment: This is the exception I am getting:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Comment: I am setting this: conn.setConnectTimeout(15000000);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(15000000);

Comment: Also this value is greater than the int range . @sai1990

Comment: Good luck to you .@sai1990